# Understanding variance explained by independent variables in Binary Logistic Regression.

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I am running a Binary Logistic Regression. I am trying to understand the amount of variance explained by each of the independent variables. Can I run the full model, record the Nagelkerke r square and then remove one independent variable, record the new r square and take the difference between the two as the amount of variance explained by the variable I removed? Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not use the rsq() and rsq.partial() functions in the rsq package for this computation? They compute several types of R squared and partial R squared coefficients for glm models such as binary logistic regression.  See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rsq/versions/1.0.1/topics/rsq and https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rsq/versions/1.0.1/topics/rsq.partial.

Comment: Thanks Isabella - do you know if this can be done in SPSS?

Comment: I don't, Melissa, but I believe that you can call R from within SPSS in the newer versions of SPSS.